# Do Single Page Website affect the page views / impression negatively with regards for Ads monitization?

Tags: google-adsense, single-page-application

I'm planning on publishing my own website, and currently deciding whether to use single page app. I have a small experience with using vueJS as my work required me and I loved how easy and fast it was but our products never incorporate ads. I have very little idea how ads work so please go easy on the explanations.

Do sites with lots of backlinks better than single page sites in terms of increasing impression / page views for ads (specifically planning on using Google Adsense)?

Comment: When you say "sites with lots of backlinks", do you mean to say "sites with lots of pages / internal links" instead? The term backlinks usually means incoming links from other websites, though it technically can refer to internal links.